# What is the way to redirect a collection page path when the product url has been changed manually?

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I Have an e-commerce platform named [Sonoor](https://sonoor.com/), and i made slug changes in the product url. Now, when i open that specific page with the collection path, i get a 404 error. How to change the collection url?

I was expecting an automatic redirect from the collection page as well.

Comment: What changes have you made? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of your issue, including the shortest code necessary to reproduce your issue. Without more information, your question could end up being [closed](/help/closed-questions) at best, or [flagged as spam](/help/promotion) at worst.